# Loop bind objects

Tags: javascript, closures, leaflet

I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem) but still have a headache on making the code work.

I have a slightly different needs. Instead of alerting I have to bind each object.
My code is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers_length; i++) {
    events_number = data.markers[i].events_number //data.markers is a multidimentional array
    marker = L.marker([ data.markers[i].latitude , data.markers[i].longitude ]); //just create the new object
    marker.on('mouseover', function(){
        return function(){
            this.bindPopup(" Found"+events_number+" event(s)").openPopup();
        }
    }(i) );
}
```

I am using leaflet if you ask. For a single object the bindPopup would work like:

```
marker.on('mouseover', this.bindPopup('hi').openPopup());
```

The trouble is that the above code gives the last object for all the. I assume that there is a problem with the `this` and the level of the functions. So how can I bind each marker with a separate text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be:

```
marker.on('mouseover', function(en){
    return function(){
        this.bindPopup(" Found"+en+" event(s)").openPopup();
    }
}(events_number) );
```

You have to pass the value that you want to be saved in the closure (`events_number` in this case), and the function has to take a parameter to receive that value and use it in the closure (`en` in my code).